# Android: How to check if a certain value is in the SharedPreference's String

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is to check if a certain value such as a `id "123"` is in the the String that has been retrieved by the SharedPreference's getPreferences  method.

I've saved the data to be appended in the SharedPreference with a comma like `String id = "123,124,125,126"` so that I could retreive it later as a array and use it .

```
 private  String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
            String[] arr = str.split(",");
            return arr;
        }
```

The problem is I wanted to do a simple if else check to see if the parameter("129") that has been passed was contained in the String id  ="123,124,125,126" with `if(!id.contains(parameter))`. Actually it should have returned true ,since 129 doesn't exist, however, itsimply ignores if and jumps to else.

```
      //this method returns sharedpreference Strings with comma such as "123,124,125"
  String myId = getStringFromPreferences(activity,defaultValue,"myId"); 

            //parameter is 129 ,therefore, this condition should jump to else
          if(!myId.contains(parameter)){
                myId = myId+","+parameter; //appends the parameter 

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not empty" ,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "empty" +favoriteList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I simply want to check the value `"129"` to see if it exists in within  the String id (String with comma `"123,124,125"` )

Comment: Code `!myId.contains(parameter)` means `myId` does not contain `parameter`. String "123,124,125,126" does not contain "129", so condition is true and works as expected.

Comment: @almasshaikh: Why would it execute else part?